# Where does return actually returns the parameters

Tags: methods, return

public class functions {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Cirle's perimeter is: " + countCirclesPerimeter(10.2));
}
public static double countCirclesPerimeter(double r)
{
    double circlesPerimeter = 2*Math.PI*r;
    return circlesPerimeter;
}
```

}

I am learning the basics of Java right now and I just wanted to ask someone to make sure that I understand it correctly:

1. System.out.println - prints the answer using the function called circlesPerimeter. Inside the parentheses I give a number that will be stored in double r variable.
2. public static double countCirclesPerimeter(double r) function takes that parameter (10.2) written above and stores it.
3. double circlesPerimeter does the calculation `2*Math.PI*10.2;`
   and now my most important question is **what is happening with the return method called circlesPerimeter?**

   I know it's already counted and stored in circlesPerimeter but when it says return it returns to the function public static double countCirclesPerimeter and now its the only thing that the function stores? Then System.out.println is executed and countCirclesPerimeter function is changed for the returned value?

Comment: With return, it returns the value of the local variable at the end of the method block...

Comment: I didn't understand the question, van you explain yourself please?

Comment: It replaces "countCirclesPerimeter(10.2)" so what will be printed is:
"Cirle's perimeter is: [the return value will be here]"

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? Once compiled it won't look like this, and when it's run it won't stay the same either. *"when it says return it returns to the function public static double countCirclesPerimeter"* - that would be returning to the method where the return statement is. It doesn't do that, it returns to where the method was called from. *"now its the only thing that the function stores?"* - the function/method doesn't store the result. The computer's memory stores the result in a way that isn't explicitly anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the method does not store anything, it process whatever code is inside. In your case the method `public static double countCirclesPerimeter(double r)` calculates `2*Math.PI*r` and is stored in the local variable `circlesPerimeter`, then the funcion returns a double (that is circlesPerimeter) and the flow returns to `main` and is printed out as a double. The static method can do this because it returns a double.